# function already defined in .obj

Tags: c++, object, header, linker, include

From what I understand, this error is caused by not properly using header guards when you have multiple files including the same file.  In my case, this is the include tree that's causing the error:

`File A includes Z, which contains the functions I need.  File B includes A, and file C includes A.`

Without any `#pragma once`'s, The program gives a bunch of variations of the same error:

```
blahblah.obj: error LNK2005: class some::namespace::ObjectType Object already 
    defined in dialogDlg.obj
```

I just was wondering, given the include tree I described, what is the proper way to get this to compile properly?

I tried using `#pragma once` on file Z, but that didn't work.  I also tried #pragma once on file A, which also didn't work.  Finally I tried it on both A and Z, also didn't work.

Comment: something gives me the idea you are not using separate header files??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you are trying to *define* a variable in a header file. If that header file is included in several source file it will be define in each source file thereby giving you the error.

Instead *declare* it as `extern` and then define in one of your source files.

So in the header file:

```
extern ObjectType Object;
```

And in a source file:

```
ObjectType Object;
```

Comment: I would just add that this has nothing to do with include guards. Include guards help to prevent including the same header in one source file *multiple times.* We're looking at a header creating problems by being included in *different* source files.

Comment: Okay so if I need access to these variables and objects in both file B and file C (both .cpp files), is there a way to achieve this cleanly?

Comment: As long as you compile b.cpp and c.cpp together, this solution already achieves what you want.